# Can I restrict Bing Autosuggest API to suggest only technical skills?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

My application let users capture and organize their online learning experiences. For this we ask for users' learning interests during onboarding. Just wanted to check if I can make use of AutoSuggestion API to provide suggestions to users. Here the intention of users is to enter something related to learning interest like JAVA, AWS, Oracle, Geography, digital marketing, SEO etc.

Ex. if user enters "ja", the application should show java, java script. Currently I get the following responses: java, jacobsconnect, jamba juice, jack in the box etc. Am using [Test API console](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56c7694ecf5ff801a090fbd1/operations/56c769a2cf5ff801a090fbd2/console) for Auto Suggest API. It finally makes this HTTP request

> GET https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/suggestions/?q=ja
>   HTTP/1.1 Host: api.cognitive.microsoft.com Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:
>   ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

I can build a curated list of skills and implement auto-fill. But am just curious to know if I can use Auto Suggest API instead. I couldn't find any useful information through their online documents.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the following response from Azure service team and unfortunately the requested feature is not possible with Autosuggest API. Please find their response below:

> Hi! We wanted to follow up and let you know that the service team informed us the functionality requested in your SO post is not part of the AutoSuggest API. They have, however, noted your interest in this type of behavior and appreciate the feedback.